# Javascript how to verify day by getDay when using timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to verify that the day of the week is equal to Wednesday (3), and this works well if I do as following.

```js
var today = new Date();

if (today.getDay() == 3) {
  alert('Today is Wednesday');
} else {
 alert('Today is not Wednesday');
}
```

But I am unable to do the same with a time zone.

```js
var todayNY = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});

if (todayNY.getDay() == 3) {
  alert('Today is Wednesday in New York');
} else {
 alert('Today is not Wednesday in New York');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the function 'toLocaleString' implies, it returns a String.
The 'getDay' exists on a Date type.

So, to use the 'getDay', You'll need to cast the String back to Date.

try:

```js
var todayNY = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/New_York"
});
todayNY = new Date(todayNY);
if (todayNY.getDay() == 3) {
  alert('Today is Wednesday in New York');
} else {
  alert('Today is not Wednesday in New York');
}
```

Comment: but `new Date()` converts the date back to the local time zone of the host for the server whether it was on the FE or BE so the line above would be useless especially if he was using a timeZone value that differs from the server's one

Comment: `getDay()` according to docs "returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time". So this answer is incorrect. The input string is irrelevant. The return value is based off system timezone.

Answer (score 11):

[**new Date().toLocaleString()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Return_value) returns a string representing the given date according to language-specific conventions. So can do this

```js
var todayNY = new Date();

var dayName = todayNY.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
    weekday: 'long'
})

if (dayName == 'Wednesday') { // or some other day
    alert('Today is Wednesday in New York');
} else {
    alert('Today is not Wednesday in New York');
}
```

Comment: the Perfect answer! and there's also several other options to add such as month, year, and day