# How can I get the day in a week in the specified timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the method `Date.getDay` to get the day in a week. But the problem is that it doesn't consider the timezone passed in.

see below code. The `date` is initialized by different timezone but they are converted to the current server timezone.

How can I make the `date` consider timezone? I don't want to use `momentjs` because it is too big.

```
> d = new Date('2020-07-02T20:00:00.000Z')
2020-07-02T20:00:00.000Z
> d.getDay()
5
> d = new Date('2020-07-02T20:00:00.000+10:00')
2020-07-02T10:00:00.000Z
> d.getDay()
4
```

I see there is a solution in this post ([Javascript how to verify day by getDay when using timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187691/javascript-how-to-verify-day-by-getday-when-using-timezone)) but how can I get the timezone value `timeZone: "America/New_York"` from the date string e.g. `2020-07-02T20:00:00.000Z` ?

Comment: seems like a solution. But how can I get the timzeone `{timeZone: "America/New_York"}` from date?

Comment: You can use `getTimezoneOffset()` which can get you offset. You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) link how to get the timezone.

Comment: this method `getTimezoneOffset` only return the offset in seconds. But timezone is string value. The link doesn't seem provide a way to get the timezone name.