# How to get numeric day-of-week for given timezone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

```js
const d = new Date(); // get 'now'
d.getDay(); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday... in my browser's timezone.
d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'NZ' }); // formatted date in NZ

console.log(d);
```

How can I get the numeric *day* in NZ? `toLocaleDateString` does not support `weekday: 'numeric'`.

The only way I can think of is to map the day to Sat, Sun ... and then use a `{Sun: 0...}` map to map it back to a number?!

EDIT: To be clear: the day-of-the week for a given time will be different in different timezones. But `Date.getDay()` only returns the numeric date in the browser's timezone. `toLocaleDateString` can present the date in different timezones, however it does not appear to support outputting the day/weekday as a number, which seems a surprising omission.

Also, I do not want to use some deprecated massive library (looking at you, moment) but instead I want to use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the day of week and the month of the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year)

Comment: @vale no, not at all.

Comment: Won't this be different for different locales. E.g. some regions start the week on Sunday, whereas others start on Monday

Comment: @Lissy93 the [getDay() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) produces a machine-standard 0 = Sun, ... 6 = Sat, *regardless of the browser's locale*. I want that function, but for a given timezone. (your deleted answer returns a string as my third line of code does...)

Comment: You can use the trick from this answer: [Javascript how to verify day by getDay when using timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187691/javascript-how-to-verify-day-by-getday-when-using-timezone) – create a date from the formatted date (keep in mind it relies on 'en-US' encoding as `dd/mm/yyyy` isn't parsed correctly by `new Date()`) You're probably better off mapping against your own object.

Comment: @artfulrobot this seems to be (as you rightly stated) an omission as no "numeric" format is provided in`toLocaleDateString` for `weekday`.

Comment: @artfulrobot for now, seems the only way is to map the weekdays to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as of April 2022, apparently there is no way! Here's my work-around:

```js
// This date is Wednesday 2022-04-20 13:00:00 at UTC/GMT
// In NZ, it is Thursday  2022-04-21 01:00:00
const d = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 3, 20, 13, 0, 0));

const timeZone = 'NZ';
const numericDayInNZ =
  ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
  .indexOf(d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {weekday:'short', timeZone}));

  console.log("At UTC date: ", d,
    "your timezone has a numeric day of:", d.getDay(),
    "and in NZ it is", numericDayInNZ);
```

- Note: if you want to use this code in your own locale, you can either change the `en-GB` and all the day names, or just leave it as-is if that's unoffensive and all you need is the number.
- The handy thing is that you can rearrange the days, e.g. to put `Sun` last if you wanted 0 = Monday.
- I think it was an oversight in the spec not to have included a `Date.prototype.getDay` equivalent in `Date.prototype.toLocale(Date|Time)?String` functions, but at least this solution is efficient enough and does not require bulky third party libs.